# XSLT templates not displaying properly

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I'm trying to apply transformations to an XML file using XSLT. I need to create a different template to apply a different formatting for the description part.
I need to define a named template titleTemplate that would display the book title
in Bold and Lightgray background.
and define only one template that would match the following elements:
`<author>, <isbn>, <yearEdition>, <publisher>`.

This is the output i'm trying to achieve:
[image]

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="book.xsl"?>
<books>
<book copies="5">
<title>XML in a Nutshell</title>
<author>E.R.Harold, W.S.Means</author>
<isbn>9780596007645</isbn>
<yearEdition>2004/3Ed</yearEdition>
<publisher>OReilly Media </publisher>
</book>
<book copies="3">
<title>Thinking in Java</title>
<author>Bruce Eckel</author>
<isbn>9780131872486</isbn>
<yearEdition>2006/4Ed</yearEdition>
<publisher>Prentice Hall </publisher>
</book>
</books>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>3b</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h2>List of Books</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="Green"><th>Author</th><th>ISBN</th><th>YearEdition</th><th>Publisher</th></tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="books">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="book/title"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:call-template name="titleTemplate"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author/text()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="isbn/text()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year/text()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="publisher/text()"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="titleTemplate">
        <xsl:sort select="title"/>
            <tr colspan="2"><td bgcolor="lightgray"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you give me an insight where i might be wrong? I just started learning templates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first, you cant use sorting in xsl:template because xsl:sort must be a children of an xsl:apply-templates or xsl:for-each element (cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-sort)
If you want to sort your books, you must place sort function in a book match template.

Second, if you want to use a named template you can pass params and use it in the template.
To pass params to named template, use xsl:with-param instruction and xsl:param instruction in the template (cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Passing-Parameters-to-Templates):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>3b</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h2>List of Books</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="Green"><th>Author</th><th>ISBN</th><th>YearEdition</th><th>Publisher</th></tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="books">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="book"><xsl:sort select="title"/></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:call-template name="titleTemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="tit" select="title/text()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author/text()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="isbn/text()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year/text()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="publisher/text()"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="titleTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="tit" />
    <tr colspan="2"><td bgcolor="lightgray"><xsl:value-of select="$tit"/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a named template, sort the `book` by `title` and write a template for that element and one for the other children of `book`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>3b</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h2>List of Books</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="Green"><th>Author</th><th>ISBN</th><th>YearEdition</th><th>Publisher</th></tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="books">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="book">
      <xsl:sort select="title"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <tr><td colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="lightgray"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="author | isbn | yearEdition | publisher"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="author | isbn | yearEdition | publisher">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>           
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I know i could do it the simple way but i'm forcing myself to learn to modularise the codes using template. Can you please try to use a named template? Just so that i could understand it better. But thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: Sorry, no, but in my view modular XSLT code uses template matching (and, if needed, modes (but modes only if you need to process some nodes twice or more times)) as much as possible, I would not use named templates, unless I needed to recursively break up string values. I really don't see why you would want to use a named template if you want to process your `title` elements and map them to a HTML table row `tr` result element. That is a task for template matching.